# Exception: cannot access a closed Stream (WinXP only!)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, dispose

I am trying [this](https://tftp4net.codeplex.com/) TFTP client for my application as Client. However, there is a bug somewhere when sometimes my program which is trying to read the stream throwing exception that the stream is already closed. After some digging in source code I found that in `TftpTransfer.cs` there is Dispose method, which sometimes called and then exception is thrown.

I can't find why sometimes Dispose method is called before I use the stream(after TFTP transfer is done) and how to address it.

Following is the code and exception occurs on setting position to 0.

```
        private static AutoResetEvent TransferFinishedEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        ....
        var client = new TftpClient("192.168.0.1");
        var transfer = client.Download("00-02.conf");
        transfer.OnFinished += new TftpEventHandler(transfer_OnFinshed);
        transfer.OnError += new TftpErrorHandler(transfer_OnError);
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        transfer.Start(stream);
        TransferFinishedEvent.WaitOne();
        stream.Position = 0;
        var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        var myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(myStr);
        ...
        static void transfer_OnError(ITftpTransfer transfer, TftpTransferError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transfer failed: " + error);
            TransferFinishedEvent.Set();
        }

        static void transfer_OnFinshed(ITftpTransfer transfer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Transfer succeeded.");
            TransferFinishedEvent.Set();
        }
```

UPD: Workaround which didn't work yet

```
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        var sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(stream.GetBuffer()));
        transfer.Start(stream);
        TransferFinishedEvent.WaitOne();
        
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

`sr` is always pointing to end of stream and it's empty.

UPD2: One thing which maybe worth to mention. Exception cannot access a closed Stream happens only on Windows XP box (.NET 3.5 which I have to stick to). I have tried on Windows 7 and even though sometimes I see the stream inside framework disposed, I don't have exception. Again, on Windows XP exception happens randomly. Approximately every 3 calls to my app throwing exception.

Comment: Have you tried `stream.Seek()`.  Also are you using any `using` directives?

Comment: Is uppercase S in `Stream.Position = 0;` a typo or is it the actual code? Might it be that you have a `Stream` variable/field/property elsewhere and you are using it instead of `stream` ?

Comment: @ne1410s: same exception about closed stream for `.Seek()`. I am not using `using` directive.

Comment: @Rubidium37: just typo, fixed. It's just simple Console application, no other code elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream appears to be closed by design in the library when it gets to the end of the download.

```
//Was that the last block of data?
if (command.Bytes.Length < Context.BlockSize)
{
    Context.RaiseOnFinished();
    Context.SetState(new Closed());
}
```

Where the Closed state just calls `Dispose()` on the instance of `TftpTransfer` (which in turn closes the stream).

I'd argue that's maybe a bug in the library - it doesn't own the stream so it shouldn't be closing it but you're stuck with that for now.

The simplest solution is to create a new memory stream to read the bytes captured like this::

```
var sr = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(stream.GetBuffer());
```

Comment: I've updated my post. The workaround didn't solve the issue. `EndOfStream` is always true and I read no data from stream. I just don't understand why sometimes Closed method called and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: One thing which maybe worth to mention. Exception cannot access a closed Stream happens only on Windows XP box (.NET 3.5 which I have to stick to). I have tried on Windows 7 and even though sometimes I see the stream inside framework disposed, I don't have exception. Again, on Windows XP exception happens randomly. Approximately every 3 calls to my app throwing exception.

Comment: I meant create the new stream `vr` *after* the ftp download has completed - the same place your original code had it. If you do it up front (as your updated snippet suggests) of course the buffer will be empty at that point.